# Detect if photo is 2d (e.g. from screen, magazine) or 3d (real photo of object)

Tags: image-processing, 3d, 2d

Scenario: You take a photo of a real apple. You then take a photo of an apple found online on your computer screen. Is it possible to determine which of these 2 images is of the real object?

I have looked into the following methods, I'm hoping someone knows a bit more to extend on them if it is possible, or to offer others:

- Use photogrammetry by taking multiple photos to build a 3d image (but ideally I want to only take 1 photo)
- Analyse lighting/levels of the photo
- Detect depth in the photo

Comment: Are you asking how to distinguish a photo from a photo of a photo?

Comment: like edge detection?

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, pretty much this.

Comment: If I showed you a picture of an apple and a picture of that picture, you wouldn't be able to tell the difference (unless that second picture was taken carelessly).

Comment: @CrisLuengo - so you do not think it is achievable? Even if it could detect depth / 3d?

Comment: Well, if you have a 3D camera, then of course you can tell the difference. You need to be able to get two pictures from different point of view, or you need a range camera. Then you can tell that what you're looking at is flat, or it's not flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could not distinguish the photo of a 3D object from a second photo of the 1st photo.

The geometric relationship between the 3D object and the 1st photo is described by perspective transformation, while the relationship between the 2nd photo and the 1st photo by projective transformation. The projective transformation is invertible, so the distortions on the two photos are similar.

If the 2nd photo is obtained by a parallel projection, it could be achievable to detect their difference.

here is a good introduction to the concepts:

http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/BEARDSLEY/node3.html